# How to translate an array with data into a widget

Tags: flutter, dart

How to translate an array with data into a widget

array

```
[{id: 1, section_name: Name1, route: Gorod(), icon: Icons.location_city}, {id: 2, section_name: Name2, route: Gorod(), icon: Icons.chat}]
```

SearchData

```
void SearchData() {
   info = new List.from(data);
   for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {

    Widget routed = info[i]['route'];

    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => routed));

 //   Widget test = Gorod();
 //   Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => test));

   }
 }
```

an error comes out

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'
```

file Gorod();

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Gorod extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return GorodState();
  }
}

class GorodState extends State<Gorod> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          iconTheme: IconThemeData (
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          title: Text('Title Gorod', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        ),

        body: Container (
             child: Text('Text fdsf fds fdsf'),
        )
    );
  }

}
```

page code where I want to go

I want to take the path from the array and then substitute it and go to the page.

Comment: How does ```Gorod()``` look inside?

Comment: looks like a regular page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As can be seen from your error you are receiving string from your List.

There is no method to convert string to widget directly, so you have to manually check what you are getting from string by comparing and then you can create widget from it.

I hope Following minimal example will clear your idea.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var info = [
    {
      'id': 1,
      'section_name': 'Name1',
      'route': 'Gorod()',
      'icon': 'Icons.location_city'
    },
    {
      'id': '2',
      'section_name': 'Name2',
      'route': 'Gorod()',
      'icon': 'Icons.chat'
    }
  ];

  List<Widget> searchData() {
    List<Widget> _list = [];

    for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
      print(info[i]['route']);
      if (info[i]['route'] == "Gorod()") {
        _list.add(RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
                context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Gorod()));
          },
          child: Text("text"),
        ));
      }
    }

    return _list;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: searchData(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Gorod extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return GorodState();
  }
}

class GorodState extends State<Gorod> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          title: Text('Title Gorod', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Text('Text fdsf fds fdsf'),
        ));
  }
}
```